# OwinStartup and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is a .NET Framework 4.6 Web API project with OwinStartup class:

```cs
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Abc.Startup))]
namespace Abc
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.UseUnity();
            config.ConfigureWebApi();

            app.ConfigureOAuth();
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

I want to serve a few pages so I added the MVC Nuget and created this controller:

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Abc.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("page")]
    public class PageController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("contact"), AllowAnonymous]
        public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

When I visit /page/contact, it gives 404:

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYvfs.png)

I think the MVC package is not 'loaded' at startup. How can it be done?

Comment: did you enable attribute routing?

Comment: It is enabled for Api controllers, but I don't know how to enable it for Mvc controllers.

Comment: add routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();  in rountconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC depends on `System.Web` which prevents MVC from running on OWIN. If you need self-hosting, you can use ASP.NET Core which does not have this limitation.